# "next"-link based on hash url. (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kinda new to javascript and have a list of links as a menu, the last button is meant to be a next button, who will go to the next link in line dependent on which page or #hash you are on currently.

```
    <li><a class="menu" href="#home"><div>Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Next</a></li>
```

So if forexample you're on the work page, the next button would send you to the about page, and if you're on the about page, it would send you to the home page.

I guess it has something to do with a array, and some javascript, since it has to work live, but no idea how to do it.

Hope someone could explain or give me a hint.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy, and doesn’t need any additional arrays:

```
$("#next").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentLink = location.hash ? $("a.menu[href=" + location.hash + "]") : null,
        next = currentLink ? currentLink.parent().next() : null;
    if (!next || next.children().attr("id") == "next") {
        next = $("a.menu").first().parent();
    }
    if (next) {
        location.hash = next.children().attr("href");
    }
});
```

(I’ve given the “next”-link the id `next` to make it easily target-able.)

What it does:

If `location.hash` contains a value, it tries to find the `a.menu` element with the according `href`.
If it’s found that, it gets the the next `LI`.
If it has found nothing, or the `LI` found contains the `a:next` link, then it gets the first `LI`.

And finally, it assigns the `href` value of the found `LI`’s (if any) first child to `location.hash`.

See fullscreen version here to actually see the hash change: http://jsfiddle.net/ve9qt/3/show/, and http://jsfiddle.net/ve9qt/3/ for the full code.